# how to detect the (Shift+Delete) key press?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, onkeydown

I'm making a custom Terminal in a C# winform.  When the user presses a key in the `TextBox` that I'm using I have to make sure that it's a valid key.  I need to prevent them from being able to delete stuff and do whatever they want.  I managed to handle the backspace and delete and others via the `KeyPress` and `KeyDown` events.  I had a problem with the user pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>.  It deletes stuff just like <kbd>backspace</kbd>.  I don't know what the integer equivalent of it is.  I made a C++ program to detect it, it was simple:

```
char c = _getch();
cout << (int)c << endl;
```

I got a -32.  It didn't work in C#.

After so many tries to encircle its value, I found that it was 0.
It worked, at least for yesterday, but now it doesn't.  I'm also able to delete stuff with the shift+delete.

Here's my key validation method:

```
private bool IsInvalidKey(char key)
{
  bool condition1 = !IsAsciiKey(key) && !IsNavigatingKey(key); // by navigation I mean: left, right, end and home keys.
  bool condition2 = (GetCaretPosition() == CaretPosition.OutsideCommandLine && !IsNavigatingKey(key));
  bool condition3 = ((key == (char)Keys.Back) && GetCaretPosition() == CaretPosition.BeginningOfCommandLine);
  return (condition1 || condition2 || condition3);
}

private bool IsAsciiKey(char key)
{
  return ((int)key > 0 && (int)key <= 127); // char(0) should be shift+delete
}
```

How can I detect this key and where (in which event, `KeyPress` or `KeyDown`?)

I'm using a normal `TextBox` control, not a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Terminal in a C# form", and why does Shift+Delete do anything in your application if you didn't explicitly add a function with that hotkey?

Comment: Your whole approach of disabling individual hotkeys seems flawed. But if you don't write more about what you're doing, it's hard to give a good alternative.

Comment: It's not a "REAL" terminal like the one in Linux, it's just a textBox that you could give it commands, those commands are programs you make and are integrated to that "terminal" .. so it resembles a terminal, every time you hit enter, I take the command you typed, I take its arguments, see if that command exists in all the commands i have, if it does, execute it with the args you passed .. etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this in the KeyDown event.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to look at each individual key through the use of the KeyDown event, what you really need to do is do all of your validation in the `TextChanged` event, and you need to validate the entire entry (not just the last character) every time anything changes.  This is the only way to support everything that the user could possibly do.  As an example, the user could use the mouse to cut or paste text in the textbox, and that doesn't trigger any key press events at all.

If you want, you can handle the key press event *as well* so that you can prevent invalid characters/key from changing the text in the first place (and causing a full validation) but that's basically like performing client side validation of a field on a webpage; it's nice to do, but since you can get around it you can't *only* use it.

Comment: for copying and pasting, I solved this problem by setting the ShortcutsEnabled property to false .. but you're right about the cutting thing .. I have to fix it .. :/

Comment: @VeXe You still have the inherent problem that text can be changed that aren't just a single key press.  The easiest way of knowing that you have supported every single edge case is to validate everything every time.  There will always be something that you've missed if you try to just look at keypress events.  Copy/pasting was just one example.  There are a number of others.